# How to handle a collection of a base class if subtype references are required, without saving things twice?

Tags: java, database, collections, polymorphism

I have some base Class A and some (B, C, D, E) different subclasses. All instances of A come from an external data source (database) and I have to infer the actual type at runtime (with marker atttributes stored in the database) and I have no option to change this behaviour.

I end up with a List allAs. At runtime several algorithms have to be executed, that perform on subclasses of A, i.e. I have some algo(List bs), algo(List cs), ... functions and to call them I need to extract all B's, C's or whatever I need from the List. 
On the other hand there are algorithms performing on collections of A's.

The following follows:

- At some point I need to save references to instances of A's
- At some point I need to save references to instances of subclasses
- All this data has to be synchronized

The question is, what are best / bad practices to achieve this?
Following solutions come to my mind:

- Stick to the List allAs and call as.stream().filter() to extract sublists of given subclasses
  each time I have to call a subclass-algorithm
- Create a seperate list for each subclass, and combine them all if I need to call an algorithm
  that acts on instances of the base class
- Do both, but then on update / add / delete actions I need to perform them on each of the lists
  (which I need anyways for the second solution)

My intuition tells me that the cleanest way would be to stick to the first principle, but this gets performance critical since I have to handle much data such that filtering the whole collection each time is not viable.

Comment: This needs more details about the whole thing to be answerable seriously IMO. Every answer will have to be very generalized at this state and could be wrong for your case. Could you try to provide more details about the data, the algorithms, the usage etc.?

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid duplicated storage if you copy the data into a list or array sorted by the element types. Then, since all elements of the same type are consecutive elements, you can use specific sub-sequences when sub-types are required:

```
Collection<A> data = externalSource();

// preparation step
class State<T> {
    final Class<T> type;
    int s, e;
    List<?> list;
    State(Class<T> c) {
        type = c;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") <U> List<U> as(Class<U> c) {
        if(c != type) throw new ClassCastException(c+" != "+type);
        return (List<U>)list;
    }
}
Map<Class<? extends A>,State<?>> tmp = new HashMap<>();
for(A a: data) tmp.computeIfAbsent(a.getClass(), State::new).s++;
int size = 0;
for(State<?> s: tmp.values()) {
    int next = s.s;
    s.s = s.e = size;
    size += next;
}
A[] all = new A[size];
for(A a: data) all[tmp.get(a.getClass()).e++] = a;
List<A> listOfAll = Arrays.asList(all);
for(State<?> s: tmp.values())
    s.list = listOfAll.subList(s.s, s.e);

// now, all lists are available, listOfAll for all As and:
List<B> listOfB = tmp.get(B.class).as(B.class);
List<C> listOfC = tmp.get(C.class).as(C.class);
List<D> listOfD = tmp.get(D.class).as(D.class);
List<E> listOfE = tmp.get(E.class).as(E.class);

System.out.println("B: "+listOfB+",\nC: "+listOfC+",\nD: "+listOfD+",\nE: "+listOfE);
```

This performs counting sort into the `A[] all` array, then all lists are created as a *view* into the array, not having storage of their own. The original collection can be dropped, leaving it subject to garbage collection.

There is one unavoidable *unchecked* operation, but note that it has an explicit runtime check to ensure safety, assuming the initialization by the code shown above.

This code is easily applicable to a different number of subclasses.

[Demo on Ideone](https://ideone.com/5YU7pN)

Comment: This is a very interesting solution. However, changes to the data would result in a linear time operation to recalculate the listOfX, so I do'nt really see the advantages of this method over the basic ones.

Comment: This is specifically for the scenario where you use the resulting lists for a longer time and want to reduce the memory occupied by the different lists. When you repeatedly re-fetch a new list from the external source, as often than you use the filtered lists, the entire question becomes moot.